# Is it possible to read multiple files at once in C#?

Tags: c#, file, io, streamreader

Is it possible to read multiple files at once in C#? I have got this so far.

```
for (int i=1; i<Foo.number_of_files+1;i++)
{
    StreamReader aa= new StreamReader (@"realtime_" + Foo.main_id + "_" + i + ".txt");
}
```

I know that I need to create a unique `StreamReader` name for each file, how to do this? Can I put the `StreamReade`r to a list? Sort of like  list of StreamReaders ? What is the best way to read multiple files at once?

Comment: This was a lot of work to clean up.  In the future, could you put a little more effort into formulating a good question, and make sure you use correct capitalization and punctuation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
var readers = new List<StreamReader> ();

for (...)
{
   var aa = new StreamReader(@"realtime_" + Foo.main_id + "_" + i + ".txt"); 
   readers.Add(aa);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would consider looking at the parallel extensions for this operation:

Parallel.For documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx

Parallel.For example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx

Code might look something like:

```
Parallel.For(0, Foo.number_of_files, i=> {
    var a = new StreamReader(@"realtime_" + Foo.main_id + "_" + i + ".txt");
    // Other read operations
    a.Close();
    a.Dispose();
});
```

Comment: Actually, I would be tempted to wrap that StreamReader in a using statement to ensure it is closed and disposed.

Comment: Reading files in parallel usually slows things down.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, Unless the files are on different drives.  I wonder if it would speed things up if an SSD is used.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it may slow things down, but would it be faster to read them one by one or in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Yes ther is no fundamental problems with reading multiple files at once, creating list-type objects of streamreaders.

The real problem that you need to consider and adress is making sure that you close and dispose of them all cleanly. And that you do not try accessing individual files with multiple objects.

Comment: You're going to need some threads also, unless you want to read one `StreamReader` at a time, in round-robin fashion.

Comment: @Robert - yes the practicalities of reading mulitple files requires threads. I think the question was about the allowability of it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see any real question but perhaps this helps:

```
List<StreamReader> SRL = new List<StreamReader>();
for (int i=1; i<Foo.number_of_files+1;i++)
{                   
    StreamReader aa= new StreamReader(@"realtime_" + Foo.main_id + "_" + i + ".txt");
    SRL.Add (aa);
}
```